# For loop incrementation causes page to stop responding

Tags: javascript

I have been using live server in vs code for learning javascript and code but I have stumbled upon a problem whenever I write some code regarding to loops my website sometimes doesn't respond for example when I use the below code it works :

```
for(let counter = 1; counter <= 10 ; counter++){Document.write("hello")}
```

But when I use the below it doesn't work and my website doesn't respond :

```
for(let counter = 1; counter <= 10 ; counter + 2;){Document.write("hello")}
```

Comment: `counter++`  is the equivalent of `counter = counter + 1` or `counter += 1`, not the equivalent of `counter + 1`. So change `counter + 2` to `counter +=2` so that you're properly assigning the value back after increasing it.

Comment: Also change `Document.write` to `document.write()` for it to show something.

Comment: The website doesn't respond because `for(let counter = 1; counter <= 10 ; counter + 2;)` is an _endless loop_.  `counter + 2` doesn't modify the value of `counter`, and so the loop never reaches its termination condition, and the script never completes execution.

Comment: Regarding the closure, I don't think this is a "typo". The OP is asking why "counter++" works and "counter +2" does not.

Answer (score 2):

`counter++` *increments* the variable "counter"; that is, it sets the variable to a value one higher than it was before; so each time around the loop, the counter increases, and will eventually reach 10.

`counter + 2` evaluates to a number 2 higher than the variable "counter" *but doesn't store it anywhere*; so every time around the loop, the counter is still 1, and will never reach 10.

To increment the counter by 2, you can write `counter = counter + 2` or the shorthand `counter += 2`